# Trying to pass a Promise to another function that then returns it, getting "Unhandled promise rejection"

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-postgres

I want to create a generic database update function that I can use to implement more customized update functions.  In a module `database.js` I have the following:

```
const {Pool,Client}=require('pg');

const pool=new Pool({
    connectionString:process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL,
    ssl:true
});

function update(sql,functionName){
    console.log(sql);
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            pool.query(sql,(err,res)=>{
                if (err){
                    console.log(functionName+": error "+err.toString());
                    reject(res);
                }
                else{
                    console.log(functionName+": non-null");
                    console.log(functionName+": result "+JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]));
                    resolve(res.rows[0]);
                }
            });
        });
}

module.exports = {
    updateConnection: function(callSid,connectionStatus){
        queryStr='update connection set hoststatus=\''+connectionStatus+'\' where hostCallSid=\''+callSid+'\' returning *';
        return update(queryStr,"updateConnection");
    },

//...various other updateSomething functions with variations on queryStr
}
```

I test this in another module `dbtest.js` as follows:

```
var db=require('./src/ivr/database');

testUpdateConnection();

function testUpdateConnection(){
    hostCallSid="yourCallSidHere";
    db.updateConnection(hostCallSid,"accepted").then(val=>{console.log(val.rows[0])});
}
```

Originally I had all the Promise creation code from `update()` inside `updateConnection()`, and it worked as expected, but because I had to copy-paste this code into every update function, I decided to refactor it into its own separate function.  Now when I run `node dbtest`, the update successfully occurs and the `console.log()` output from `update()` is shown, but then I get the following:

```
(node:10) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at db.updateConnection.then.val (/app/dbtest.js:73:77)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:10) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
```

It seems that `updateConnection()` isn't being treated as a promise-returning function, even though it's passing along the promise returned from `update()`.  Is there a way that I can solve this without having to include the code from `update()` in every one of the update functions in `database.js`?

Comment: @alexmac `res.rows` is defined; I just added `console.log(functionName+": result "+JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]));` inside `update()` to verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update()` function has already gotten the first row in `resolve(res.rows[0]);`.  So, when you try to do that again with `val.rows[0]`, that won't work.  That's like trying to do `res.rows[0].rows[0]` which throws an exception.

Change your function from this:

```
function testUpdateConnection(){
    hostCallSid="yourCallSidHere";
    db.updateConnection(hostCallSid,"accepted").then(val=>{console.log(val.rows[0])});
}
```

to this:

```
function testUpdateConnection(){
    hostCallSid="yourCallSidHere";
    db.updateConnection(hostCallSid,"accepted").then(val=>{console.log(val)});
}
```

Or, change `update()` to just `resolve(res)`.  One or the other.

Comment: changing it from `val.rows[0]` to `val` worked, thanks